# AngularJS Form how to display radio buttons and data from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm not able to display correctly the json data.

- How can I display The radio buttons from my **json** file ([plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/klfgWkFldQFUlCZ93axO?p=preview))?
- Aslo I'd like to **validate** the form, on submit.

html:

```
<my-form ng-app="CreateApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

        <fieldset>
            <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
              <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>
              <input 
                    ng-required="{{field.required}}"
                    value="{{options.value}}"
                    type="{{field.type}}" >

              <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.required}}"></form-error>
              <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}"></form-error>
            </div>


        </fieldset>

        <button type="button" ng-click="onValidate(); return false;"> Validate</button>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"> Submit </button>
    </form>


</my-form>
```

Comment: use a dynamic form module like angular-formly instead of re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate a value on controller first

```
        $scope.richestClub = {};

        $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response;
        var fields = response.fields;
        $scope.richestClub.val = fields.answer.options[0].value;
        console.log($scope.richestClub);
        console.log($scope.fields);
      });
```

Html:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
          <fieldset>
            <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
              <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>
              <input ng-if="field.type != 'radio'" ng-required="{{field.required}}" value="{{options.value}}" type="{{field.type}}">
              <div ng-if="field.type == 'radio'">
                <div ng-repeat="option in field.options">
                  <input type="{{field.type}}" ng-model="richestClub.val" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</br>
                </div>

              </div>



              <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.required}}"></form-error>
              <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}"></form-error>
            </div>
          </fieldset>

          <button type="button" ng-click="onValidate(); return false;"> Validate</button>
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"> Submit </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: HI Korte, thanks for looking at this.  please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/fK6NL8G6zgaTp7d4zM4P?p=preview is it like this?

Comment: Yes, see my editted answer. You should also initiate the value just afer you read the json file. `$scope.richestClub = fields.answer.options[0].value;`. (Do not oforget to change the `ng-model='richestClub'`)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fK6NL8G6zgaTp7d4zM4P?p=preview like this? is it supposed to do something?

Comment: I need to submit the form to another mocked API endpoint which returns true or false depending on whether the answer provided was correct, and display this response in the UI!! no flipping idea how!

Comment: You should take a look here then:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: @user3699998 Please don't be a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). One question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can iterate over the radio options. I agree with @charlietfl that you should use an Angular form library like [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/) instead.

```
<fieldset>
  <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
    <div ng-if="field.type === 'radio'">
      <span>{{field.label}}</span>
        <div ng-repeat="option in field.options">
          <label for="{{option.label}}">{{option.label}}</label>
          <input ng-required="{{field.required}}"
                 value="{{options.value}}"
                 id="{{options.label}}"
                 type="{{field.type}}" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="field.type !== 'radio'">
      <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>
      <input ng-required="{{field.required}}"
             value="{{options.value}}"
             type="{{field.type}}" >
    </div>
    <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.required}}"></form-error>
    <form-error ng-show="{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}"></form-error>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, Oregon, is it possible also to validate the form, on submit?

Comment: Please open a separate question for that. If you use formly it will be obvious how to do validation.